# Move file as root preserving ownership linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, command

OS: Debian.
I want to be able to move files and folders around as root and from the command line without changing it's owner and group.
Is this possible?

Comment: Offtopic for Stackoverflow. You probably want to ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: where did you experience that moving files as root changes permissions? it shouldn't.

Comment: @mata I was using mv command to move a file from x user and group. When I moved the file as root it was now owned by root and root group

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux and belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mata it seems permissions are changed if the file is being moved between filesystems

Answer (score 16, accepted):

rsync :

```
 -A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
 -X, --xattrs                preserve extended attributes
 -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
 -g, --group                 preserve group
     --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
     --specials              preserve special files
```

man rsync

Comment: Thanks a lot Radu, I never thought of rsync for local use. It worked. I added the --remove-source-files flag so that it acts as the `mv` command. So it'll be like thís: `#rsync -o -g --remove-source-files source dest`

Comment: Probably worth noting that `--remove-source-files` removes the files continuously as the move progresses. That's different from `mv` which only does so after the entire operation is complete.

Answer (score 10):

The `mv` command preserves ownership and time-stamps.
For the `cp` command there are various command line options you can use. For example

```
cp -p file1 file2
```

`man cp` will display all the available options

Comment: I'm using mv command and the ownership and group changes. I need an mv like command.

Comment: Check to make sure your `mv` command is not aliased. Perhaps it is secretly calling `cp` behind the scene. Type `alias` to see all your aliases.

Comment: Mine is not aliased and it does not preserve anything.

Comment: If you move files between different file systems (partitions) then the owner can change.